# What is included on the Frecciarossa Executive class?

Tags: trains, italy, trenitalia

I've seen reviews and travel videos where passengers on the Frecciarossa executive class order full meals and drinks at their seat, all at no extra cost. However when I look at the Trenitalia site I get text like "the traveller can choose among 3 different complete menus characterized by the use of Italian products of excellence, composed of a main dish, a snack, a dessert and a mini bottle of water" ([1](https://www.trenitalia.com/en/frecce/frecciarossa_1000.html)), which seems more restricted and a far cry from a free bar. Seat61 talks about "complimentary cold tray meal".

So I'm confused about what I would actually get if I booked a ticket.

Comment: Do you have a link to those travel videos which imply free bar?

Answer (score 9):

Based on what the internet has to say, it seems that there is a complimentary meal included in the Frecciarossa Executive class. However, the content of the meal depends on the route you are travelling on. On long routes, you can choose between different menus, whereas on shorter routes the meal is in fact a drink and a snack. You are definitely not getting a free bar on either kind of route.

Quoting from [the Italian Trainline wepbage](https://www.thetrainline.com/it/compagnie-ferroviarie/frecciarossa/livello-executive#:%7E:text=Viaggia%20in%20Executive%20sui%20treni%20Frecciarossa&text=Ampie%20poltrone%20in%20pelle%20con,pasto%20gourmet%20servito%20al%20posto) (emphasis mine):

> ### Ristorazione in Frecciarossa Executive
>
> Il servizio di ristorazione per il livello Executive è curato nei dettagli e caratterizzato da ingredienti di altissima qualità.
>
> Il servizio a bordo è curato nei minimi particolari e prevede la disponibilità di prodotti di qualità e di bevande durante tutto il viaggio, caffè iperespresso illy, spremute d’arancia e pasti gourmet con piatti caldi o freddi, serviti al posto a colazione, pranzo, aperitivo e cena. Menu ispirati alle tradizioni regionali e alle eccellenze gastronomiche italiane con una ricetta d’autore firmata dallo chef Carlo Cracco, a pranzo e a cena. L’offerta di giornali e riviste è garantita durante tutto il viaggio dall’ edicola di bordo.
>
> **Sulle relazioni Torino-Milano, Torino/Milano-Venezia, Milano-Udine, Torino/Milano-Trieste, Genova-Venezia è invece previsto un servizio di benvenuto con bevande calde e fredde, caffè illy iperespresso, accompagnati da uno snack dolce e salato, e, al mattino, un quotidiano a scelta.**
>
> Inoltre, grazie al nuovo servizio Easy Bistrò puoi ordinare comodamente dal tuo posto gustosi prodotti e menù pensati per ogni momento della giornata, scegliendo tra un’ampia selezione di prodotti del Bar/Bistrò: snack dolci e salati, panini e tramezzini, primi piatti caldi e freddi, bevande analcoliche ed alcoliche.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Servizio ristorante a bordo
>
> Bevande calde e fredde, spremute di arancia e caffè iperespresso Illy sono disponibili durante tutto il viaggio.
>
> I pasti gourmet inclusi nel biglietti comprendono piatti caldi o freddi che vengono serviti direttamente al posto. Sono disponibili dei menù per la colazione, il pranzo, l'aperitivo e la cena.
>
> **Su alcune rotte, al posto del servizio catering ti verrà offerto un servizio di benvenuto con bevande calde e fredde, caffè illy e snack dolci e salati.**

which roughly translates to:

> ### Catering on Frecciarossa Executive
>
> The catering service for the Executive level is studied in detail and characterized by the highest quality ingredients.
>
> The service on board is studied in detail and provides for the availability of quality products and drinks throughout the journey, illy hyper-espresso coffee, freshly squeezed orange juice and gourmet meals with hot or cold dishes, served at your seat at breakfast, lunch , aperitif and dinner. Menus inspired by regional traditions and Italian gastronomic excellence with a signature recipe signed by chef Carlo Cracco, for lunch and dinner. The supply of newspapers and magazines is guaranteed throughout the journey from the on-board newsstand.
>
> **On the Turin-Milan, Turin/Milan-Venice, Milan-Udine, Turin/Milan-Trieste, Genoa-Venice routes, a welcome service is provided with hot and cold drinks, illy hyperespresso coffee, accompanied by a sweet snack and salty, and, in the morning, a newspaper of your choice.**
>
> Furthermore, thanks to the new Easy Bistrò service, you can order tasty products and menus designed for every moment of the day from the comfort of your seat, choosing from a wide selection of Bar/Bistrò products: sweet and savory snacks, sandwiches and sandwiches, first courses hot and cold, soft and alcoholic drinks.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Restaurant service on board
>
> Hot and cold drinks, freshly squeezed orange juice and Illy hyper-espresso coffee are available throughout the journey.
>
> The gourmet meals included in the ticket include hot or cold dishes that are served directly at your seat. Menus are available for breakfast, lunch, an aperitif and dinner.
>
> **On some routes, instead of the catering service, you will be offered a welcome service with hot and cold drinks, illy coffee and sweet and savory snacks.**